# Problem with uploading local git repo to gitlab via instruction of gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project under a directory on my local machine and I initialized it and all its subdirectories as a git repo.

To be very explicit, instead of initializing the git repo on an empty directory, the directory already had non-empty subdirectories in it.

I then did the following to turn it into a repo. Assume the directory is in

> /home/user/project

`cd /home/user/project`

`git init`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "initial commit`

All files, including all sudirectories and associated files seemed to have been committed ...
I was a bit surprised that "." acted recursively but was happy about it.

Now, I wanted to upload the repo to gitlab.

Gitlab has the following instructions.

Push an existing Git repository

`cd existing_repo`

`git remote rename origin old-origin`

`git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:example/example.git`

`git push -u origin --all`

`git push -u origin --tags`

When I tried the first command with the repo,

`git remote rename origin old-origin`

I obtained

> fatal: No such remote: origin

What does this mean? Why is this and what am I supposed to do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any remote named "origin" so, just skip `git remote rename origin old-origin` command and continue the remaining commands

Comment: Thank you! is this really ok? So that bit was just in case my repo was name "origin"? P.S.  I can only accept an answer within 7 minutes, so will have to wait. But honestly, why is this step then included?

Comment: well, it's normal to have an origin in a repo but you don't have cause you just did init/add/commit (did not set remote anymore) so, you don't need to rename the remote .. just set the remote by `git remote add ...` and push to the remote repo!

Comment: Well, I am unsure, I just skipped that step and followed the rest and it seems to have worked. I'm just new to this and want to make sure I don't mess up steps that might mix up results later on.

Comment: @PLee: a repository itself doesn't have a name. More precisely, it doesn't "own" or "possess" a name. You obviously have to call it something to *get* it or get *to* it, but it doesn't know its own name, which means that you can move it from place to place freely. The `origin` that you see *in* a repository is what Git calls a *remote*. This is a short name that you stick into your repository in which you store a URL for some *other* Git repository.

Comment: As Sajib Khan notes, the usual process for creating some Git repository is to start with `git clone <url>`. This `git clone` process is shorthand for a six-step sequence that includes "make new empty repository" followed by "add URL and store it under the name origin", then "run `git fetch origin`" and other steps. You didn't use `git clone`, so you didn't get these six steps.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that: it just means that you created a repository from scratch, rather than creating one by copying a bunch of commits from some other repository. But by skipping some of those six steps, you also skipped the one that would have created an `origin` name.